# Узнать находятся ли элементы на одном листе при печати

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

с помощью  wkhtmltopdf я формирую pdf файл, который содержит таблицу, а после блок со служебной инфой. Мне необходимо, что если несколько листов в документе, то на листе с блоком  шла хотя бы одна строка таблицы + заглавная строка таблицы. Как мне вычислить есть на одном листе таблица и блок со служебной инфой?

Comment: Только вручную, используя js, высчитывать положение ваших блоков и сравнивать с размером страницы.